# In TortoiseSVN, how do I re-integrate a Branch if our server is only running SVN v1.4 and re-integration is not supported?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a SVN branch that I branched off from the Trunk several revisions ago. I have merged the branch with changes from the trunk to keep it in sync. Now I would like to finally integrate my Branch with the Trunk. What is the best way to go about this? I cannot use the re-integrate option because our SVN server version is only 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Messy - but export the code on your branch to a main, check the chances and commit?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this very thing this morning. Here's what worked for me:

I merged from my branch into trunk using the "Merge from a range of revisions" option. I selected every revision my branch had. In my case, there were a minimal number of files with actual conflicts which I fixed via the conflict editor. A majority of the files and folders had tree conflicts. I was able to fix all of them by simply resolving each conflict individually, using the "local copy" (trunk).